# Minecraft Server Paper player.setResourcePack doesn't work

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft

I'm currently working on a Plugin, which lets Players decide, whether they want to load a 16x16 ResourcePack or a 32x32 one. The packs are forced (they're needed for the gameplay). My problem is, that when I select a pack it should do this:

```
p.setResourcePack("https://github.com/Ole1Tau1/RPG/blob/main/RPGPack.zip", "E3CED908E76C7390DDC4F47C22F6FF16", true);
```

But instead of loading it, the client gives me an error:

> Server resource pack couldn't be applied
> Any functionality that requires custom resources might not work as expected

[image: The Error]

Anybody got an idea what I did wrong?

Full code is here BTW: https://github.com/Ole1Tau1/RPG/tree/main/RPSelector/src/main/java/dev/onetone/rpg/rpselector

Comment: Your repository seems to be private :/

Answer (score 1):

Your repository seems private. So, only you -with your account- can access to it. With this, for all players that tried to download it, it will return 404 error.

To fix this, you can:

1. **Make your repository public.** I think you don't want, but if it contains only the zip file, it's fine.
2. **Create a second repository to host it.** It can be a good solution if you already have another repo with a wiki or other help that are public.
3. **Use something else to host it.** A website on the server where spigot is running, another website or anything else, you can host the zip file then change the link in your plugin.